# BouncyCastle: Extract public key informationfrom Certificate Signing Request

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am using Bouncy Castle library in Java for reading CSR. I need to extract the public key information from CSR. I can see that openssl is able to extract required information from CSR.

I can't find any way to do this in BouncyCastle. I have been able to read PKCS10CertificationRequest object from the CSR. I have seen examples using SubjectPublicKeyInfo for extracting public key. But the code relies on the fact that algorithm of public key is already known. I can do a "instanceof" operation for various algorithm parameters and match but I think there would be something better. I want to derive the algorithm from CSR itself. I tried to find this information but couldn't find anything related to this. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: I also am looking to resolve the PublicKey type from a CertificateSigningRequest parsed via a Pkcs10CertificateRequest instance. Actually the SubjectPublicKeyInfo contains the AlgorithmID (ASN.1 ObjectIdetifier (OID)) and in the Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs namespace is a PkcsObjectIdentifiers class containing the ObjectIDs and their respective values, but no structure to allow the resolution of the algorithm type!!? Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to create a new wrapper around the PKCS10CertificateRequest like this:

```
 JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest jcaCertRequest =
        new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest(pkcs10CertRequest.getEncoded()).setProvider("BC");
```

This class has the `getPublicKey()` method.

```
 PublicKey publicKey = jcaCertRequest.getPublicKey();
```